# Failed to convert property value 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to String

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, thymeleaf

I am trying to upload an image using *spring boot* and getting the error below:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Nov 15 22:02:20 IST 2021 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad
> Request, status=400). Validation failed for object='contact'. Error
> count: 1 org.springframework.validation.BindException:
> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'contact' on field 'imageUrl': **rejected
> value**
> [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@1520a5ef];
> codes
> [typeMismatch.contact.imageUrl,typeMismatch.imageUrl,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [contact.imageUrl,imageUrl]; arguments []; default message
> [imageUrl]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
> 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
> to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'imageUrl'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Cannot convert** value
> of type
> 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
> to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'imageUrl': **no
> matching editors or conversion strategy found**]

```
<form action="#" th:object="${c}" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/user/processContact}" method="POST" class="mt-2">
                            <!-- First Name  -->
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text ">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input required type="text" id="firstName" name="name"
                                    placeholder="Enter Name here" class="form-control" />
</div>                              placeholder="Enter Nick Name here" class="form-control" />
</div>
<!-- Contact Image  -->
<div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="imageUrl" />
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Save Contact</button>
</div></form>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processContact(@ModelAttribute Contact c, @RequestParam("imageUrl") MultipartFile file ,Principal p)
    {
        System.out.println(c);
        try {
            System.out.println("Contact = "+c);
            User u=this.uR.getUserbyUsername(p.getName());
            System.out.println("User = "+u);
            //
            if(file.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No filr choosen!!");
                return"User/addContact";
            }
            else {
                c.setImageUrl(file.getOriginalFilename());
                File save = new ClassPathResource("/static/IMG/UploadedIMG").getFile();
                Path path = Paths.get(save.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+file.getOriginalFilename());
                Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                System.out.println("Image Uploaded");
                c.setUser(u);
                //System.out.println("Contact = "+c);
                u.getContactList().add(c);
                
                this.uR.save(u);
                //System.out.println("Contact = "+c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return"User/addContact";
    }
```

```
package com.SmartManager.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Contact")
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int contactId;
    private String number; 
    private String imageUrl; 
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 500) 
    private String description;
    private String work; 
    private String nickname;

    @ManyToOne() 
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public int getContactId() { return contactId; } public void setContactId(int
            contactId) { this.contactId = contactId; } public String getNumber() { return
                    number; } public void setNumber(String number) { this.number = number; } public
    String getImageUrl() { return imageUrl; } public void setImageUrl(String
            imageUrl) { this.imageUrl = imageUrl; } public String getName() { return
                    name; } public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; } public String
    getDescription() { return description; } public void setDescription(String
            description) { this.description = description; } public String getWork() {
                return work; } public void setWork(String work) { this.work = work; } public
    String getNickname() { return nickname; } public void setNickname(String
            nickname) { this.nickname = nickname; } public Contact() { super();}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a `cURL` for this network call ?
Your error log says that it is unable to find a requestParam with name as 'imageUrl" and since you've not declared `@RequestParam(optional = true)`, controller is throwing 400 error, i.e.  bad request.

If you're using multipart file you should probably use @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam.

```
https://your-url.com/request/pathVar/page?param1=value
```

Use `@PathVariable("pathVar")` to access get the path variable
Use `@RequestParam("param1")` to access the request params declared ? delimiter in the url.

I doubt if a multipart file will ever be part of your request parameter.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/user/processContact

Comment: I have tried @RequestPart also but the same error is coming

Comment: Post the cURL through your network tab in the browser to see what you're actually sending.

Comment: Not able to paste the whole log Please help me with below logs
curl "http://localhost:8080/user/processContact" ^
-X "POST" ^
-H "Connection: keep-alive"-H "Content-Length: 163901" ^
-H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" ^
-H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"95^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"95^\^", ^\^";Not A Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^"" ^
-H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^
-H "sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\^"Windows^\^"" ^
-H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" ^
-H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" ^
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundaryXrJFT13wWnWBFXpY" ^

Comment: I won't be able to help with this incomplete request, this only contains headers from your request. Can you please mention the cURL in your question

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I fix this, you can try it.

in thymeleaf form, at `type="file"` input we no need to add `th:field="*{image}"`, just like this:

```html
<div class="form-group input-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-form-label">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/register")
public String createAccount(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model 
    model, HttpServletRequest request,final @RequestParam MultipartFile file, 
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttr) throws IOException {}
```